# How would I get a text-align:right object to be centered on mobile in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I would like to put a header and a button on the same horizontal line but on opposite sides of the page (left and right). I'm using Twitter Bootstrap so I've put them in a .row and then specified that they each are .col.sm-6. I put the button in a div, so I could move it to the right of that column with text-align:right.

How could I make that button center itself on mobile? When the window gets smaller and the second column jumps under the first, the button is still right-aligned.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <h1 class="col-sm-6">Resources</h1>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <button style="text-align:right">Sign up your event</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `class` for your button like `<button class="button">Sign up your event</button>` and then use `@media-queries` to center it using the following CSS when the window size is reduced to mobile width, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
     .button {
          display: block;
          margin: 0px auto;
     }
}
```

Here's a working demo (view as full page and then reduce your browser window):

```css
.outfitcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.outfit img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.outfit,
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
}
.outfit {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
}
.outfitcontainer:hover .outfit {
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outfit:hover + .overlay {
  z-index: 50;
}
.overlay:hover {
  z-index: 50;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.overlay p {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 50%;
}
.overlay p:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 50%
}
.price,
.item {
  font-family: "Brandon Grotesque Medium";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 25%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.oldprice {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #383838;
  font-size: .75em;
  line-height: 25%;
}
.designer {
  font-family: "Didot Light Italic";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 25%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.second-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.button {
  text-align: right;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="col-sm-6">Resources</h1>

  <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <button class="button">Sign up your event</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you! I learned something really powerful today!